# How to close a local server connection using Swift in the terminal?

Tags: swift, localhost, vapor

I'm following a simple tutorial on using Vapor to setup a local server and it works by going to it in a web browser.  Now I would to know if there is a swift command to end or close this server?

Here is the current state of the terminal:

```
Last login: Wed May 23 10:06:45 on ttys209
Laurences-MacBook-Air:server laurencewingo$ pwd
/Users/laurencewingo/desktop/server
Laurences-MacBook-Air:server laurencewingo$ swift run
Compile Swift Module 'Server' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/Server
Started on port 2252
```

The command 'swift run' started the server but now I would like to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> makes the terminal send the foreground process a `SIGINT` (interrupt signal). Processes that receive that signal can choose how to respond, but conventionally, they clean up and close themselves gracefully.